# MongoDB PHP: How do I get ObjectId with a JSON feed? (it's blank)

Tags: php, json, mongodb, feed, database

I'm storing a file through GridFS and saving the id like so:

```
$file_id = $gridfs->storeUpload('texture');
$item = array(
    'name'=>$_POST['name'],
    'description'=>$_POST['description'],
    'price'=>$_POST['price'],
    'categories'=>$category_array,
    'tags'=>$tag_array,
    'file'=>$file_id
 );
 $collection->insert($item);
```

and through terminal and doing find() "file" returns:
ObjectId("4cbe9afe460890b774110000")

If i do this to create a JSON feed so i can get info back for my application "file" is blank... why is this?:

```
foreach($cursor as $item){
            $return[$i] = array(
                'name'=>$item['name'],
                'description'=>$item['description'],
                'file'=>$item['file']
            );
            $i++;
        }
        echo json_encode($return);
```

The strange thing, to me, is why can I do:

```
foreach($cursor as $item){
echo $item['file'];
}
```

and get it back tho?

Oh, and here is what the feed returns:

```
[{"name":"Tea Stained Paper 1","description":"Grungy paper texture stained with tea and coffee.","file":{}},{"name":"Worn Metal 1","description":"A grooved, worn old metal texture","file":{}}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure, but maybe

```
echo json_encode($return, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

is what you need to do.

It also could be, that you need to convert `$item['file']` to utf8

```
utf8_encode($item['file']);
```

before assigning it to the `$return` array.

Comment: Thanks! The first thing, although not the answer is awesome. I didn't know that existed. Im using that now. And, UTF8 made it work!

Answer (score 1):

MongoIds keep their values tucked away in an invisible field.  It has no visible fields, so there's nothing to convert to JSON, hence `{}`.  If you'd like to have json_encode do the "right" thing, vote for http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-154.

Echoing a MongoId converts it to a string, that's why it behaves differently.

Comment: So, how do I do it? I need to echo it out?

Comment: Nevermind! But i do wish this worked without having to convert to utf8!